# Contact deleted from phone but still visible in WhatsApp

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

First i deleted chat from WhatsApp, then i deleted contact from my phone. Then i refreshed WhatsApp 2-3 times but when i type name in search bar, that contact is visible in WhatsApp without any previous chats.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp (like some other apps) makes clones of contacts.  So, for a particular contact, there is a Phone/Sim entry and there is a Whatsapp entry.

To delete from Whatsapp.

- Search for Contact on Whatsapp
- Press on 3 dots
- Select View Contact

Then

- You can block the Contact

Or

- Press on 3 dots
- Select View in Address Book
- Select More
- Select Delete

If you have a whole lot to do then a Contact Manager App can make it easy.  I use **Contacts Optimizer** (I am not associated with it)

---

To prove it, here is a screenshot from Contacts Optimizer.  This is page 2 of the accounts, I am showing this page to show `Whatsapp`.

[image]